# How to install cyapa trackpad driver in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I know there's a package for synaptics, xserver-xorg-input-synaptics but what about cyapa meaning Cypress trackpack, is there a package for it? The situation arises from a Chromebook conversion to EFI firmware